# Different ways to initialize Javascript Date object and getting different results each way

Tags: javascript, date, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference in initialization of two dates in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159789/difference-in-initialization-of-two-dates-in-javascript)

I am getting a weird result concerning the initialization of Javascript Date objects. 
I am trying to initialise 1st Feb 2012 to a JavaScript Date object.
1st way is through the constructor, and I get the required result (1st Feb 2012).
2nd way is through an empty constructor, and setting each field, and result I get is totally different. (2nd March 2012). This way works when I set month to months of January, March, May though. But fails when the months are February, April, June.

Please refer to the code below.

Code Excerpt 1:

```
var year = 2012;
var mth = 1;
var dy = 1;
var hrs = 0;
var min = 0;
var sec = 0;
var ms = 0;

//Result here gives me 1st Feb 2012
var dt = new Date(year, mth, dy, hrs, min, sec, ms);
alert("Date 1 : " + dt.toString());

//Result here gives me 1st March 2012
var dt2 = new Date();
dt2.setFullYear(year);
dt2.setMonth(mth);
dt2.setDate(dy);
dt2.setHours(hrs);
dt2.setMinutes(min);
dt2.setSeconds(sec);
dt2.setMilliseconds(ms);
alert("Date 2 : " + dt2.toString());
```

I would appreciate if someone help explain why this is happening.
Is this a JavaScript bug?

Thanks.

==================================================================================

Update: Found the solution on this thread.
[Difference in initialization of two dates in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159789/difference-in-initialization-of-two-dates-in-javascript?rq=1)

Current date at time of writing is 31st Jan 2013. DateTime() gives current date and time, hence dt is 31st Jan 2013.

Hence when dt.setMonth comes first, it tries to set 31st Jan 2013 to 31st Feb 2013, which is invalid. Hence Javascript defaults it to 31st March 2013.

Then the dt.setDate comes in, Javascript changes the date to 1st March 2013. The order matters when we set dates in Javascript.

Comment: @nnnnnn sorry. fixed it already. typo

Comment: Think I found the cause. Exact problem on this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159789/difference-in-initialization-of-two-dates-in-javascript?rq=1